# Beginner boolean algebra

Tags: logic

I'm an absolute beginner to boolean algebra, learning about logic circuits and am having a hard time with simplifying my expression.

Starting with three inputs (A, B, and C) and ending with two outputs (X, Y) I'm having trouble simplifying output Y.

[image]

I've been going in circles trying a bunch of possibilities, but can't seem to figure out the best next step to get things any simpler. Instead, they only seem more complicated.

What I have so far:

```
X   = ((A*B’)’ + (B*C’))’
    = ((A*B’)’)’ * (B*C’)’
    = (A*B’) * (B*C’)’
Y   = [(A+C’)’ * ((A*B’)’ + (B*C’))’] + [(A+C’) * (((A*B’)’ + (B*C’))’)’]
    = [(A+C’)’ * ((A*B’)’ + (B*C’))’] + [(A+C’) * ((A*B’)’ + (B*C’))
    = [(A+C') + (A*B')' + (B*C')]' + [(A+C’) * ((A*B’)’ + (B*C’))
```

Comment: It looks $X$ simplifies to $AB'$. Plug that in $Y$ expression and simplify :  $$Y =  AB' \oplus (\overline{A'C}) = \overline{AB' + A'C} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep applying DeMorgan's Law until there's only one layer of negations. Distribute until you get everything into sum of products form. Try to look for factoring tricks to simplify:
\begin{align*}
X
&= ((AB')' + (BC'))' \\
&= (AB')(BC')' \\
&= AB'(B' + C) \\
&= AB'B' + AB'C \\
&= AB'  + AB'C \\
&= AB'(1  + C) \\
&= AB'(1) \\
&= AB' \\
\end{align*}
Hence, we have:
\begin{align*}
Y
&= (A + C')'X + (A + C')X' \\
&= (A + C')'(AB') + (A + C')(AB')' \\
&= (A'C)(AB') + (A + C')(A' + B) \\
&= (A'A)(B'C) + (A + C')(A' + B) \\
&= 0(B'C) + (A + C')(A' + B) \\
&= (A + C')(A' + B) \\
&= AA' + AB + A'C' + BC' \\
&= 0 + AB + A'C' + (1)BC' \\
&= AB + A'C' + (A + A')BC' \\
&= AB + A'C' + (ABC' + A'BC') \\
&= (AB + ABC') + (A'C' + A'BC') \\
&= AB(1 + C') + A'C'(1 + B) \\
&= AB(1) + A'C'(1) \\
&= AB + A'C' \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Why not stop 6 steps into $Y$ when you got to a perfectly good minimal product of sums? :)

Comment: @genisage Hahah, that's true.

Comment: @genisage No, actually that one was deliberate. The $BC'$ term is covered by the other two terms. This is know as the Consensus Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem).

Comment: @Adriano Can you elaborate on what you mean by the "BC' term is covered by the other two terms"? Very clear answer with a bunch of tricks I would have never seen. Thanks.

Comment: @user25976 A longer explanation is given in the Consensus Theorem Wikipedia link above. But in general, simplifying Boolean Expressions is usually done through the use of Karnaugh Maps (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), which is a cool visual tool that involves covering a grid with rectangles.